# Clip a Container in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, clipping

I want to clip a container as shown in the attached image.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Jk8I.png)

Thank you.

Comment: use ClipRect and do the math!  https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipRect-class.html

Comment: will it be bottom bar? perhaps you need https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/CircularNotchedRectangle-class.html

Comment: @KirillMatrosov Yaa kind of but not exactly because don't want to use BottomAppBar, I know it has shape parameter. I want to make a custom widget.

Comment: @diegoveloper I tried to do math but was not able to get the exact shape.

Comment: i am agree with other comments. first create CustomPainter ( you can copy paste ) , then start from 1 corner...and line to ..line to..line to.. until you reach first point.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`CustomPaint`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html) to draw a [round rectangle](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/RRect-class.html) and [`ClipRect`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipRect-class.html) to only render its half to be a "notch."

```dart
ClipRect(
  child: Container(
    color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
    height: 50,
    width: 200,
    child: CustomPaint(
      painter: CustomPaintNotch(),
    ),
  ),
),

...

class CustomPaintNotch extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.green;

    Offset center = Offset(size.width / 2, 0);
    // As a notch, RRect will be drawn with offset
    // With ClipRect used, paint outside the area won't be rendered
    RRect roundRectangle = RRect.fromRectAndRadius(
        Rect.fromCenter(center: center, width: 100.0, height: 40.0),
        Radius.circular(20.0));
    canvas.drawRRect(roundRectangle, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

CustomPaintNotch paints a round rectangle at the edge of the top-center part of the Container widget. Since ClipRect was used, paint beyond the area won't be rendered. This will be the notch of the rectangle.

Here's how the widget looks like when rendered.

[image: demo]

Complete sample

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // ClipRect was used so paint beyond ClipRect area won't be rendered
        child: ClipRect(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            height: 50,
            width: 200,
            child: CustomPaint(
              painter: CustomPaintNotch(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomPaintNotch extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.green;

    Offset center = Offset(size.width / 2, 0);
    // As a notch, RRect will be drawn with offset
    // With ClipRect used, paint outside the area won't be rendered
    RRect roundRectangle = RRect.fromRectAndRadius(
        Rect.fromCenter(center: center, width: 100.0, height: 40.0),
        Radius.circular(20.0));
    canvas.drawRRect(roundRectangle, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```